# newSession - from parent session configurations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

when we create new session using newSession(), would the new session inherits all config properties set from parent session?

As per the spark doc (https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.newSession.html), newSession() returns a new SparkSession as new session, that has separate SQLConf, but shared SparkContext and table cache. Could not follow the difference between SQLConf and SparkContext in this context. In the following case, would spark_session_2 inherits all properties of spark_session_1?

```
spark_session_1 = builder.appName('app_name').config('prop1','val1').getOrCreate()
spark_session_1.conf.set('prop2','val2')

spark_session_2 = spark_session_1.newSession()
```